# Connections from domain laptop are refused by non-domain laptop

Tags: active-directory

Connections from domain laptop are refused by non-domain laptop. I have a Win10 laptop on a domain. And a Win7 laptop not on the domain. All connections from domain to non-domain are refused. For example, putty telnet to 3389 gets a “Network error: Connection refused” message. Except ping. Ping works. The domain laptop can ping the non-domain laptop just fine. Windows firewall is turned off on the non-domain laptop. Only ip addresses are used to attempt connection, so not a DNS problem. This has got to be a routine problem but nothing from Google helped. End goal is for domain machine to use SMB share on non-domain machine and rdp from domain machine to non-domain machine. But the problem seems to be traffic not getting to non-domain machine as evidenced by the telnet test.

Comment: Traffic is getting to the computer, as evidenced by your ping test. Your problem is that the computer is not accessible via RDP or SMB. Do you have RDP enabled on the computer? Do you have any shared folders on the computer? How are you testing SMB connections to the computer?

Comment: @joeqwerty SMB test: try to open the share by IP in FileExplorer.

Comment: ICMP is geting through.  No evidence of any IP traffic getting through.